# Calculating Viewport dimensions and displaying it dynamically with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this functions to calculate the viewport width and height dynamically as the browser window size changes. Now I want to display that values on screen, but it does not work. Any ideas?

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
             $('viewport').html(viewportWidth);
             $('viewport').html(viewportHeight);
        $(window).resize(function() {
             $('viewport').html(viewportWidth);
             $('viewport').html(viewportHeight);
        });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="viewport">width and height should be displayed here dynamically</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the error console in Firefox, Chrome or Safari? Maye there an error message had been occured. Another one is, I miss the event 'onResize', so the reading and writing the value will be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issues:

- You are using `.html`, which overwrites the previous html of the element. You could use `.append`.
- You are using the variables you only initially set, rather than fetching new values when the window resizes.
- You are using `"viewport"`, it should be `"#viewport"`
- You should also make sure the elements exist when your code runs, which means dom ready handler or putting the script element after the elements

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#viewport').empty().append($(window).width(), "x", $(window).height())
    }).resize(); //Initial call
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lbb7/2/

Comment: Thank you so much!. Can't believe I missed the #...Thanks, this is perfect, really appreciate.

Comment: What exactly does the .empty() function do here?

Comment: It clears out previous content before appending into it, see http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: @DextrousDave you could also use `.html( $(window).width() + "x" + $(window).height() )` instead of `.empty().append(...)`, dunno why that didn't occur to me earlier

Comment: which is better, or is it color and colour?

Comment: But I'm actually glad you did it like that, so I will know how to use those two functions in future...

Comment: `.empty().append()` vs `.html()` (specifically with the `.empty` in there) is color and colour except `.append()` takes multiple arguments where as `.html` only takes one.